# Where would I ask about a specific game database's existence?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'd post on https://gaming.stackexchange but I am not sure if the question would be rejected as not a real question or wrong community.

My question is basically this:

> Where can I find a *Final Fantasy 7* database? A database that includes every piece of information concerning the game's element (Enemy, Enemy skills, materials, magic, statuses, weapons, characters, allies, dialogs, etc). Does it exist?

Where should I post this question?

Answer (score 3):

You are actually asking for off-site resources. Those question don't add much value to the network since the site will end up being just a link database. There is no knowledge added here.

That makes the question pretty much off-topic on any site on the network. Maybe Quora or some other sites can help you.